# Pointer Logic Exercise in C

Tags: c

I am trying to understand pointers and the different declarations. I was provided with an example with pointer logic but I cannot figure out how it works exactly.

I was giving the following piece:

```
int i, j, *p, *q;
i = 10;
p = &j;
q = malloc(sizeof(int));
*q = i;
j = i;
q = p;
*q = 5;
printf("%d %d %d %d", i, j, *p, *q);
```

It says that the outcome is 10 5 5 5 but I canno get behind why.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you expect? How the actual is different from actual?

Comment: What is the question?  It prints that because i is 10, j is 5, and p and q both point to j.

Comment: A pointer is an object whose value is the address of another object.  You access the object to which the pointer points by using the unary `*` prefix operator. You access the pointer itself if you use it *without* the `*` operator.  You obtain a pointer value either by applying the unary address-of operator (`&`) to an object, or by one of the dynamic memory allocation functions, such as `malloc`.

Comment: The code you show is simple to anyone that understands pointers but to someone new to pointers is probably intimidating.  I would check your books / online tutorials for simple explanations of pointers until it becomes clearer to you.  Once you grasp how pointers work with a few lines of code, the example you posted is just a matter of working through it step by step.

Answer (score 3):

Drawing is the best way to figure out pointer manipulation.
(It's much faster on paper, though.)

```
  i              j
+----+        +----+
| 10 |        |    |
+----+        +----+

[p = &j; p is the location of j]
  i              j
+----+        +----+
| 10 |        |    |
+----+        +----+
                 ^
                 |
                 p

[q = malloc(sizeof(int)); q is the location of an unnamed int]
  i              j
+----+        +----+        +----+
| 10 |        |    |        |    |
+----+        +----+        +----+
                 ^             ^
                 |             |
                 p             q

[*q = i; replace the value of the int that q points to with i's value]
  i              j
+----+        +----+        +----+
| 10 |        |    |        | 10 |
+----+        +----+        +----+
                 ^             ^
                 |             |
                 p             q

[j = i; replace the value of j with the value of i]
  i              j
+----+        +----+        +----+
| 10 |        | 10 |        | 10 |
+----+        +----+        +----+
                 ^             ^
                 |             |
                 p             q

[q = p; replace the value of q with the value of p, i.e. they are both &j]
  i              j
+----+        +----+        +----+
| 10 |        | 10 |        | 10 |
+----+        +----+        +----+
               ^  ^
               |  |
               p  q

[*q = 5; replace the value of the int that q points to with 5]
  i              j
+----+        +----+        +----+
| 10 |        | 5  |        | 10 |
+----+        +----+        +----+
               ^  ^
               |  |
               p  q
```

Comment: A picture is worth 1,024 words (of an unspecified bit-length).

Answer (score 1):

Notice three statements:

- `p = &j;`
- `q = p;`
- `*q = 5;`

So, `*q`, which is the same as `*p`, which points to `j`, is set to a value of 5.

So, all the three expression, `j`, `*p`, `*q` yields the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a step by step explanation of what the code does and how the value of the variables change. I'll recommend that you use a debugger and single step the code and inspect each variable after each step.

But here it goes:

```
// Define two int variables (i and j) and two int-pointer variables (p and q)
int i, j, *p, *q; // i: uninitialized j: uninitialized p: uninitialized q: uninitialized 

// Assign 10 to i
i = 10; // i: 10, j: uninitialized, p: uninitialized, q: uninitialized

// Make p point to j
p = &j; // i: 10, j: uninitialized, p: points to j, q: uninitialized

// Allocate some memory for q
q = malloc(sizeof(int)); // i: 10, j: uninitialized, p: points to j, q: points to uninitialed memory

// Assign i to the memory that q points to
*q = i; // i: 10, j: uninitialized, p: points to j, q: points to memory containing 10

// Assign i to j
j = i; // i: 10, j: 10, p: points to j, q: points to memory containing 10

// Make q point to the same as p
q = p; // i: 10, j: 10, p: points to j, q: points to j

// Assign 5 to the memory that q points to (which is j)
*q = 5; // i: 10, j: 5, p: points to j, q: points to j

// print i (10), j (5), the memory p points to (j aka 5), the memory q points to (j aka 5)
printf("%d %d %d %d", i, j, *p, *q); // Print 10 5 5 5
```

Notice:

```
q = p;
```

represents a memory leak as there no longer is a pointer to the dynamic allocated memory.